# Trigo problem : Find the value of $\tan \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\sin^2x\right), x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: trigonometry

Trigo problem : 
Find the value of $\tan \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\sin^2x\right), x \in \mathbb{R}$

Let $f(x) = \tan \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\sin^2x \right), x \in \mathbb{R}$

therefore, $-\infty < f(x) < +\infty$

I am unable to understand how to proceed further.. please suggest.. thanks..

Comment: I would not expect to be able to improve on the expression for general $x$.

Comment: sultan: Do you mean you want to find the range, i.e., the set of all values of the function?

Comment: Just plug a $\large x$ value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\because-1≤\sin x<1 | x \in \mathbb R$$
$$\therefore 0≤\sin^2x≤1$$
$$\therefore0≤\left(\fracπ4\sin^2x\right)≤\fracπ4$$
$$\therefore 0≤\tan\left(\fracπ4\sin^2x\right)≤1$$
$$\tan\left(\fracπ4\sin^2x\right)\in\left[0,1\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

All I can say regarding
$\tan((π/4)\sin^2x)$
is that
$0 \le \sin^2x \le 1$
so
$0 \le (π/4)\sin^2x \le \pi/4$
so
$0 \le \tan((π/4)\sin^2x) \le 1$
since
$\tan(\pi/4) = 1$.

Comment: knowing, of course, that $\tan x$ is continuous and strictly increasing in that interval

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=tan(\frac{\pi}{4}sin^2(x))$ then $f(x)\in[0,1]$.